# why can I open undef?

Tags: perl, file-io, undefined

The following does not die:

```
open my $in, '<', undef or
    die q{couldn't open undef};
print <$in>;
```

Neither does this:

```
open my $in, '>', undef or
    die q{couldn't open undef};
print $in 'hello';
```

I don't understand why neither of these die. How could opening `undef` possibly be successful?
The reason I found this was that a guy I work with had done this:

```
open my $in, '>', $ARGV[0] or die q{couldn't open $ARGV[0]};
```

He thought that this would kill the script if no arguments were passed in (I know this isn't the cleanest way to do that but I didn't think it wouldn't work).

I'm using Strawberry 5.16.1.

Comment: See http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=799021

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See `perldoc -f open`:

> As a special case the three-argument form with a read/write mode and
>   the third argument being `undef`:
>
> ```
> open(my $tmp, "+>", undef) or die ...
> ```
>
> opens a filehandle to an anonymous temporary file.

Comment: I thought that too, but it's not being opened read/write. I suspect it's undocumented behavior related to this but am not certain of that.

Comment: I can confirm that Perl 5.10.1 and 5.18.1 both behave this way, with `'>'` as well as `'+>'`.  It might be interesting to know which versions of Perl do this.

Comment: @Oesor It works for all modes: read-only, write-only, read-write. In any case opens a an anonymous temporary file. But read-only or write-only modes have no practical application.

Comment: Maybe I'll send a documentation patch for that, then.

Comment: I'm not sure that's a behaviour Perl should be committed to providing by documenting it.

Comment: I was looking for a way to portably open `/dev/null`.  This might be a crude way of doing it, e.g. `open($fh,'>',undef)`.  It would be portable, but rather kludgey.  Anyone know of a better way to direct output to oblivion?